# Comparing Money and Decimal(13,4) columns in SQLServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have 2 different columns in 2 tables, one is with Money datatype in table1 and another one with Decimal(13,4) in table2.I need to sum values in table2 and compare it with value in table1(HAmount).
However i found values like below, please suggest how to compare this.

```
Table1
HAmount
120.4500

Table2
DAmount
60.2285 
60.2200

IF(HAmount=SUM(DAmount))
BEGIN
    Success
END
ELSE
    Failed
```

Comment: Please clarify what you want.  Do you want the `Decimal(13,4)` value to be rounded and treated as a `Money`?

Comment: Yes, How to Round OFF and COmpare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert everything to `DECIMAL (13,2)`:

`IF(CAST(HAmount as DECIMAL(13,2) = SUM(CAST(DAmount as DECIMAL(13,2)))`

With default rounding settings this should give you the desired output without having to factor in "behind-the-scenes" decimals that aren't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the convert / cast chart at this [Microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). It says that there is an implicit conversion between Decimal and Money.

You might consider using the BETWEEN keyword to help you with fractional pennies.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these datatypes [money and decimal(13,40)] can accurately store values with four decimal places. The full values may or may not be displayed, depending on how SSMS or the user interface of your choice are configured, but they are there. That money value of "120.45" may actually be 120.4485, and the display is rounding it up for you. If not, and if the two values are supposed to add up to the one, then it would seem that you somehow have ended up with corrupt data... and that's a different and more serious problem.

---

To round numeric functions in T-SQL, you use the `ROUND` function. Here's a quick example:

```
declare
  @Foo1 money
 ,@foo2 decimal(13,4)

set @Foo1 = 66.2285
set @Foo2 = 66.2285

print @foo1
print str(@foo1, 7,4) + '  ("true value" of the money value)'
print @foo2

print ''
print round(@foo1,2)
print str(round(@foo1,2), 7,4) + '  ("true value" of the ROUNDED money value)'
print round(@foo2,2)
```

You want to be very wary when working with imprecise values (i.e. rounding is required), particularly when you're dealing with money!

Comment: How to ROund Off 120.4485 to 120.45

Comment: Updated my answer with a rounding sample